# How to install Microsoft.Azure.Devices NuGet package for Unity?

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, iot

I was working with Unity and Hololens and tried to establish connection to Azure Iot Hub via MQTT protocol. Microsoft provides [a tutorial for getting started with Azure IoT Hub in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted), but unfortunately, I encountered a problem with the tutorial:

[image]

In the picture above, I have selected Microsoft.Azure.Device NuGet package for installation. I have tried version 1.0.0 and also the latest one available, 1.2.4. The projects were automatically generated by Unity and that is probably the reason, why I do encounter this problem. Which problem? After I try to install the selected NuGet, I encounter the following error:

> Could not install package 'Microsoft.Azure.Devices 1.2.4'. You are
>   trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v3.5,Profile=Unity Full v3.5', but the package
>   does not contain any assembly references or content files that are
>   compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the
>   package author.

I was like, "Hmm, I must have wrong .NET framework version. I wonder if I can change that..." I tried to go to project properties like this

[image]

Microsoft advises changing .NET framework from **Properties** context menu item:
https://technet.microsoft.com/fi-fi/library/bb772098(v=vs.90).aspx (4.24.2017)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202(v=vs.100).aspx (4.24.2017)

However, this feature must be blocked by something, because the view that is supposed to open flashes white and disappears immediately. I suppose Unity doesn't like people tinkering with project properties, but what else can I do? Incompatible .NET framework issue needs to be resolved, so that the NuGet package can be installed, but how do I do that?

In short, *how to install Microsoft.Azure.Devices NuGet package for Unity?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't possible due Unity's restriction to .net 3.5.

To be exactly, they use a custom version of mono-2.

---

*You could try the new `(experimental) .net 4.6` settings in Unity 5.6.*

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/upgraded-mono-net-in-editor-on-5-5-0b4.433541/

[image]

Comment: Oh. Well, tried out to change Api Compatibility Level, only to find out I cannot change it. I'm deploying for Hololens and I think Hololens is not very happy to support this experimental setting... Drat!

Comment: @HenriKorpela Add this information to your Q. I haven't any clue how HoloLens works with Unity3D.  I thought always it's just a "WinRT" build.

Comment: Didn't mention Hololens, because I thought it really wouldn't matter that much, especially when it's quite a new product. I mean, obviously it's gonna work out... Right? XD But anyway, I'll add this detail to the question.

Comment: What's your C# application type? UWP?